# Rewrite old dynamic .asp page to new page using .htacces

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have created a new website with php. I have to rewrite quite a few urls from my old site. However, I need to rewrite an old dynamic .asp page to my new page.

E.g.
Old url
`mysite.co.uk/productdetails.asp?pid=617` (I have quite a few like this with different numbers on the end)

to the new URL

```
mysite.co.uk/Casio-CDP-Digital-Piano-in-Black/302
```

As you can see the pid is not the same as the new number on the end so I need to rewrite all the urls. I have tried the following:

```
RewriteRule "^productdetails.asp?pid=617/$" /Casio-CDP120-Digital-Piano-in-Black/302 [L,NC,R=301]
```

But the error message I get is the productdetails.asp page doesn't exist.

Any help welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't match against the query string in the rule's pattern. You have to use a `RewriteCond` and the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pid=617/?$
RewriteRule ^productdetails\.asp$ /Casio-CDP120-Digital-Piano-in-Black/302? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply however this doesn't work. If I remove the /$ after the 617 the right page shows up however the url is: my site.co.uk/Casio-CDP120-Digital-Piano-in Black?pid=617. How do I avoid the ?pid=617 behind the url.

Comment: @Ria sorry, forgot to add `?`'s

Comment: Thanks so much. That worked and displays the url correct. :-)